# linkTo generates a href to an /<App.Object:ID>, not to /ID

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Unfortunaltely, the example for links in the Ember guides (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/) does not work somehow for me.

To show a list of tempworkers, and have a link for each tempworker to the detail page, I use the following code:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tempworkers">
  <div>
    {{#each controller }}  
      <tr>
        <td>{{#linkTo 'tempworker' this}} {{firstname}} {{/linkTo}}</td>
        <td>{{initials}}</td>
        <td>{{completeSurname}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tempworker">
  <div id="tempworker">
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='firstname'}}</p>
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='initials'}}</p>
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='surnamePrefix'}}</p>
    <p>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding='surname'}}</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    ENV.EXPERIMENTAL_CONTROL_HELPER = true;
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision    : 11,
    adapter     : DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        url     : 'http://dev.start.flexplanners.com/api'
    })
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('tempworkers'); // /tempworkers
    this.route('tempworker', { path: '/tempworkers/:id' }); // /tempworkers/:id
});

App.TempworkersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return App.Tempworker.find(); // return All tempworkers to the TempworkersController
    }
});

/* TODO: Question -> According to http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/, this should be working by convention, and NOT explicitely defined here?
 * But when I leave it out, it's broken :(
 * */
App.TempworkerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
        return App.Tempworker.find(params.id); // return tempworker by id to the TempworkerController
    }
});
```

Use cases:

```
When I visit the URL /tempworkers, the app fires a request 
to my server API, and return the list in my tempworkers view.

When I visit the URL /tempworkers/[UUID], the app fires a 
request to my server API, and return the requested tempworker 
in my tempworker view.

When I click a generated link in the list of tempworkers, the app routes me 
to /tempworkers/<App.Tempworker:ember343:47cfa9f2159d45758ceacc4c15ae1671>, 
and shows the details in my tempworker view
```

My questions are as follows:

1) Are these 3 use cases showing expected behaviour?

2) If yes, does this show a distinction between 2 states, 1 is a fresh URL visit (including server API call), and 1 transitionTo another view, with a parsed in reference to a single object from the list?

3) If yes, when will be a moment to reload the list, and update the items in the list?

4) If no, how will I be able to have the linkTo generate a href like '/tempworkers/[UUID]', and let the app make a server API call to get the details of the tempworker?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Rainer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it right, you've just made a typo, your route needs to be `/tempworker/:tempworker_id`.

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('tempworkers'); // /tempworkers
  this.route('tempworker', { path: '/tempworkers/:tempworker_id' }); // /tempworkers/:id
});
```

Ember uses the provided dynamic key when looking for a model to deserialize.

Comment: Just to clarify, because it's especially counterintuitive for someone coming from Rails, you have to use the /:<model>_id convention and cannot customize that to just use /:id.